# ActiveModel::SecurePassword undefined method `password_digest='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activemodel

I try to use rails 3.1 ActiveModel::SecurePassword by following http://bcardarella.com/post/4668842452/exploring-rails-3-1-activemodel-securepassword

and I end up with red light ...

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, :presence => { :on => :create }
end
```

factory.rb

```
Factory.define :user do |f|
  f.email "foo@bar.com"
  f.password "foobar"
  f.password_confirmation { |u| u.password }  
end
```

spec_user.rb

```
describe User do
  it "should authenticate with matching username and password" do
    user = Factory(:user, :email => 'frank@gmail.com', :password => 'secret')
    User.authenticate('frank@gmail.com', 'secret').should == user
  end
end
```

and i get a red light ...

```
 Failure/Error: user = Factory(:user, :email => 'frank@gmail.com', :password => 'secret')
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password_digest=' for #<User:0xb383460>
```

and I thought it was rake db:migrate problem and I look into rails c , but obviously password_digest is defined.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > a = User.new
 => #<User id: nil, email: nil, password_digest: nil, is_admin: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 > a.password_digest = 3
 => 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was getting the same issue, and found a (what I think is) a better solution in the following comment:

http://bcardarella.com/post/4668842452/exploring-rails-3-1-activemodel-securepassword#comment-281584959

basically, you need to add a password_digest field to your model with a migration. Before then, it'll add a password_digest= method, but it won't be saved, and the method won'tr show up in factories and the like

Answer (score 1):

solved by

```
describe User do
  it "should authenticate with matching username and password" do
    user = Factory(:user, :email => 'frank@gmail.com', :password => 'secret')
    User.find_by_email('frank@gmail.com').try(:authenticate, 'secret').should == user
  end
end
```